# Difference between BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCK_OPS and BPF_PROG_TYPE_CGROUP_SOCK

Tags: linux, sockets, kernel, ebpf

The BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCK_OPS and BPF_PROG_TYPE_CGROUP_SOCK programs seen to be very similar. According to the [kernel source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/bpf_types.h), the following are the definitions of the two program types:

```
BPF_PROG_TYPE(BPF_PROG_TYPE_CGROUP_SOCK, cg_sock,
          struct bpf_sock, struct sock)

BPF_PROG_TYPE(BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCK_OPS, sock_ops,
          struct bpf_sock_ops, struct bpf_sock_ops_kern)
```

Is the CGROUP_SOCK a subset of the SOCK_OPS program type? Because its associated `bpf_sock` seems to have common fields as `bpf_sock_ops`.

**Edit:** While testing, I also realized that the `bpf_sock` struct only allows restricted access to the source and destination IPs. Does this reinforce that CGROUP_SOCK is a subset of the SOCK_OPS program type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the commit that introduced the `BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCK_OPS` program type: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/40304b2a1567fecc321f640ee4239556dd0f3ee0

The following is from the commit message which outlines the differences quite nicely:

> Created a new BPF program type, BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCK_OPS, and a corresponding
> struct that allows BPF programs of this type to access some of the
> socket's fields (such as IP addresses, ports, etc.). It uses the
> existing bpf cgroups infrastructure so the programs can be attached per
> cgroup with full inheritance support. The program will be called at
> appropriate times to set relevant connections parameters such as buffer
> sizes, SYN and SYN-ACK RTOs, etc., based on connection information such
> as IP addresses, port numbers, etc.
>
> Although there are already 3 mechanisms to set parameters (sysctls,
> route metrics and setsockopts), this new mechanism provides some
> distinct advantages. Unlike sysctls, it can set parameters per
> connection. In contrast to route metrics, it can also use port numbers
> and information provided by a user level program. In addition, it could
> set parameters probabilistically for evaluation purposes (i.e. do
> something different on 10% of the flows and compare results with the
> other 90% of the flows). Also, in cases where IPv6 addresses contain
> geographic information, the rules to make changes based on the distance
> (or RTT) between the hosts are much easier than route metric rules and
> can be global. Finally, unlike setsockopt, it oes not require
> application changes and it can be updated easily at any time.
>
> Although the bpf cgroup framework already contains a sock related
> program type (BPF_PROG_TYPE_CGROUP_SOCK), I created the new type
> (BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCK_OPS) because the existing type expects to be called
> only once during the connections's lifetime. In contrast, the new
> program type will be called multiple times from different places in the
> network stack code.  For example, before sending SYN and SYN-ACKs to set
> an appropriate timeout, when the connection is established to set
> congestion control, etc. As a result it has "op" field to specify the
> type of operation requested.
>
> The purpose of this new program type is to simplify setting connection
> parameters, such as buffer sizes, TCP's SYN RTO, etc. For example, it is
> easy to use facebook's internal IPv6 addresses to determine if both hosts
> of a connection are in the same datacenter. Therefore, it is easy to
> write a BPF program to choose a small SYN RTO value when both hosts are
> in the same datacenter.

---

> While testing, I also realized that the bpf_sock struct only allows restricted access to the source and destination IPs. Does this reinforce that CGROUP_SOCK is a subset of the SOCK_OPS program type?

No, one is not the subset of the other, they are simply different program types intended for different use-cases. They have different contexts and each program type can have very specific rules around which fields are read-only and write-only.